# How to return tabled data from an procedure in an Informix database

Tags: informix

Im trying to return multiple rows of data from an existing table (table1) from a procedure.

I'm using RazorSQL and Informix 12.x.
With MSSQL this was simple but with Informix I can't seem to get it right.

```
drop function if exists test_multi;

create FUNCTION test_multi()
    RETURNING MULTISET(table1 NOT NULL);
    return select * from table1;
END FUNCTION;

EXECUTE FUNCTION test_multi();
```

I get : ERROR: A syntax error has occurred.
I could use an assist.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error most likely relates to the RETURNING statement where the element type(s) of the table need to be specified. In addition the results need to be returned as a MULTISET.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(c1 int, c2 int, c3 char(8));
CREATE FUNCTION p1()
RETURNING MULTISET(ROW(c1 int, c2 int, c3 char(8)) NOT NULL);
RETURN MULTISET(select * from t1);
END FUNCTION;
```

And an example of using it with dbaccess:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, -1, "abc");
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(2, -2, "defg");
EXECUTE FUNCTION p1();

(expression)  MULTISET{ROW(1          ,-1         ,'abc     '),ROW(2          ,
              -2         ,'defg    ')}
```

Comment: Ok it looks like the answer I was searching. I found it hard to find code samples on the IBM site. Thanks a lot.